# How do I make a Minecraft server that I have on my computer public?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I recently created a Minecraft 1.8.9 server on my computer, and was wondering how I could host this server, so my friends and me could play together while not being in the same network.
Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: See some of the answers to the linked post. It should be exactly what you are looking for.